# When chopsticks catch the booster by the grid fins, what is the maximum vertical speed?

Tags: spacex, landing, spacex-starship, spacex-super-heavy, grid-fins

[image]

How much vertical speed can the grid fins handle before breaking off?

Comment: I think we will see what is too much on their first recovery attempt @Star-SpaceX

Comment: I think we need to distinguish two cases: too much to recover the booster, and too much to recover even the engines..

Comment: I assume this question is talking about the booster @Antzi

Answer (score 2):

[image]The vehicle is Not caught by the grid fins, there are catch points just below the fins for this purpose, my understanding is velocity will be virtually Zero as the vehicles can/will hover into position. Hope this helps

Comment: Though the information you've provided is correct, the question isn't about a nominal landing where the vehicle successfully manages to arrive at the tower hovering, it's about the limits of the landing system.

Comment: That would also require you to provide the final total weight of the booster to define. Suffice to say that it would need to be Very Low velocity, cms/sec not m/sec. Sorry I can't be more specific.

Comment: Can you show some working out if we guess at the final weight?  Say the dry weight of Super Heavy, [200,000kg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Starship#Super_Heavy_booster), plus 30s propellant reserve, [19,500kg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Raptor), so 219,500kg total?

Comment: I thought that the catch points were only used during the lifting to the launch mount. 
Do they really intend to make the booster hover so precisely as to coincide perfectly on the dot with the catch points? Is that REALLY possible? If so it blows my mind.